# How to Delay XAML Binding until after Loaded

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Look at this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Cache.Colors}" />
```

This binds the ItemsControl to a static property called List. In this case, the Colors property is part of a class called Cache.

But there is a problem. When you bind in this way, the Colors property is called during the Initialize method, prior to when Security is established in the application.

Because Security has not been established, then calling Colors results in an exception as Security is a requirement for successfully calling the data service.

The solution moves this from XAML to code behind and ensures it is executed in the Loaded event instead of in the constructor during Initialize.

The real problem here is, I would like to do this in XAML. Is it possible?

Comment: Why can't you “initialize security” before opening the window, or before calling `InitializeComponent()` in the Window's constructor?

Comment: It's MainWindow. I could create PreMainWindow, I suppose.

Comment: so what? You can have code in App.xaml that's called before the window is created or in MainWindow's constructor before the XAML is actually read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to run it in the App.xaml.cs before anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I have typically solved this by having the ItemsSource being bound to implement the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface. At initialization the items source would be empty, and then at load time the items source is populated. The population of the items source raises the collection changed event, causing your items control to rebind/add the new items in the source.

Comment: This does not work because the Collection property will fail and never raise the Changed event since the Binding considers it in an error state.

Comment: Can you post your XAML and view model? Using a notifying item source shouldn't be throwing an error.